# UL for Semantic Lists and Headings

Tags: html, semantics, html-lists

I generally use `ul` for lists of items

```
<ul class="users">
  <li class="user">
    <div class="name">Jack</div>
    <div class="gender">M</div>
    <div class="salary">$15k</div>
    <div class="rank">Burger Flipper</div>
  </li>
  <li class="user">
    <div class="name">Jill</div>
    <div class="gender">F</div>
    <div class="salary">$17k</div>
    <div class="rank">Fry Tosser</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When creating a heading for this list, is it best to include the heading as part of the list

```
  <li class="user head">
    <div class="human-attributes">This is:</div>
    <div class="job-attributes">They are:</div>
  </li>
```

or should it be a separate list?

```
<ul class="users head">
  <li class="user">
    <div class="human-attributes">This is:</div>
    <div class="job-attributes">They are:</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Either one is not semantic. This looks like tabular data - why are you not using a table with `thead`?

Comment: My example is poor but my question is still about lists; these answers have given me the insight that I need.

Comment: I updated my example to make it a little less ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depends on what you want to do with it .. .You really should be using:

```
<table><thead></thead><tbody></tbody></table>
```

constructs which are meant for content you are describing, instead of <li> embedding a <div> which is going to get rendered in a bizarre way by default.

You can then use CSS to control the behaviour.

Comment: I think my example was bad. Imagine, instead, the list of questions when you go to http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @JoshJohnson even then if the data is tabular with more than one column you should use a table.  If you are thinking of displaying complex unrelated lists of information then you can use <divs></divs> within <divs></divs>. Using divs within an <li> element is a bit like using a div inside a <p> element.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still torn about `<div>`s inside of `<li>`'s since `<li>` is a block element and even a list of items may need to be marked up. In my case the data is semantically a list but business wants a "heading look", hence my dilemma. Ideally there would be no heading or the labels would be included: `<div class="name"><span>Name:</span> <span>Jack</span></div>`, maybe even a `<label>` down the road as this may become a selectable list of check boxes.

Comment: @JoshJohnson ah ... if that's the case, then i would say take hint from the complex table semantics and implement the heading as a separate entity inside a container class so something like a <div class="list-container"><ul class="head"><li>blah blah<li></ul><ul class="data"><li class="entry">blah blah</li></ul></div><!-- end container -->

That will provide the most flexible structure to you from positioning, relative positioning and manageability

Comment: Yeah, it's a weird situation. I took sort of a hybrid approach and used nested divs instead of a `<ul>` for the "heading". I used the same classes so they got styled the same way plus bold/borders for being the `.head` class. The "data" itself received a class of `.data` to aid in styling the odd rows, hover, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the legitimate uses of tables in HTML. You should not semantically be using unordered lists to present "tabular" data (which is what you are describing). You should be using something like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Jack</td>
      <td>M</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>F</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -2):

http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/listheader.html
Was a working draft.
For now your solution seem the best. but maybee whit a different class.

Comment: The HTML 3 spec is not something you should be linking to.

Comment: Html3 is obselete, but the point of this quesyion is exactly the working draft. And all this to say, there is no better solution than is actual one.